# Customizing Google Drive UI

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am handling G suite domain for our org. We have a requirement where users from Team Drive must provide Comments before deleting any files from Team Drive.

​I've searched and found that we need to write Chrome Extension in order to Customize Team Drive's HTML (via Content Scripts).

My query is latest Google Drive uses HTML 5 and I am not able to Locate HTML element for my Delete button, hence I am not able to fire my custom content script on Delete button.

My current Content script which is being called on every `Div` `onClick`

```
$('div').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("aria-label"));
    if($(this).hasClass('h-sb-Ic h-R-d a-c-d'))
    {
        alert('I am groot');
    }       
});
```

Any suggestions/ideas on how to achieve this customization? Also if there is any better way to achieve this then please suggest.

Comment: Have you already read https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk?

Comment: Yeah!! I've developed some of my own utilities with that as well. But unfortunately Drive SDK will only provide an option to add item in 'Open With' menu. I want to customize 'Delete' button in Team Drive.

Comment: Can you give more debug information on how I can better understand your problem? Like let me ask you, are you sure jquery already is loaded, do you get any alerts when you click on a div?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the alert but my issue is somewhat different. Like I can not find exact element /id 'Delete' button represents on Drive screen. So if I am clicking on 'Delete' button multiple 'Div' alerts are getting triggered.